Phantomに関してログイン出来ない件
I launch the Phantom app, press the bottom right of the screen, press the top right of the screen, and it does not jump to the login screen. So I'm having trouble logging in. I don't know much about the details of the operation, so please help me get to the login screen. thank you.
